# RPC_CSTR' : undeclared identifier while compile c++ using Nmake

Tags: c++, rpc, uuid, visual-studio-2003

I use rpcrt4.lib to generate dll. While generate dll using nmake ( cl.exe compiler) in Visual studio 2003 .Net, getting following error

```
nstaller\UUIDGenerator.cpp(35) : error C2065: 'RPC_CSTR' : undeclared identifier
installer\UUIDGenerator.cpp(35) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
installer\UUIDGenerator.cpp(68) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cl.exe' : return code '0x2'
```

Cause :
 I use following function

```
 UuidToStringA(&uuid, (RPC_CSTR*)&str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to link to `rpcrt4.lib`, which it sounds like you did.
But you also need to:

```
#include "Rpcdce.h"
```

This error

```
error C2065: 'RPC_CSTR' : undeclared identifier
```

Means that it doesn't know if this is a class, variable name, etc. That's why it needs the header file.

Comment: Ya I ve linked using /libpath "c:windows/system32" and also I included rpcrt4.lib in compiler option also,

Comment: Okay good, that is half of what you need. Did you add the `#include` to your `UUIDGenerator.cpp` file?

Comment: It looks like `"Rpcdce.h"` should include `"rpc.h"`. In the second file they declare `typedef CHAR* RPC_CSTR;`. You can try explicitly `#include "rpc.h"` to see if that works.

Comment: nope, still I am getting same error ( I added "rpc.h")